# When can we interchange partial and total derivates?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have a question regarding a math proof, which can be found on 17 (Lemma 4) on this [document](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.01981.pdf). A screenshot is provided below.

I am a bit unsure how equation 29 is derived. They seem to be using some sort of
interchange of partial derivatives, but I don't understand the justification of switching partial derivative for the total derivative.

[image]

Comment: The big issue is that the notation for partial derivatives isn't great.  I suggest you read Fite's "Total and Partial Differentials as Algebraically Manipulable Entities".  https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07958

Comment: @johnnyb, thanks for the recommended reading. In what sense do you mean "the notation for partial derivatives isn't great" -- in the general sense or in the context used in the figure posted?

Comment: the problem with the differential notation is that there is a leakage between the numerator and the denominator.  In the notation $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$, there is information *about* $\partial z$ in the denominator, and the denominator is actually usually referring to a total differential.  The notation suggested in the paper would have it written as $\frac{\partial(z, x)}{dx}$, thus having the total differential in the denominator.  I did not look in-depth, but I think that would clear up your questions with "switching" between partial and total differentials.